# js client script register client script block C#

Tags: javascript, c#, popup

I Want To Display following javascript code in my webpage. But it's not showing anything. 
The following is my code:
C# code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert3", "alert3();", true);
```

Aspx:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function alert3() {

        alert("Pnr Already Exist");
    }
```

I have no idea about JavaScript but my superior demanded that he wants to show a message in JavaScript.

Comment: Is your `alert3` function located on the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @user3378165 yes

`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alert3() {

            alert("Pnr Already Exist");
        }

        function alert2() {

            alert("Your Records Saved SuccessFully");
        }
           
    </script>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ScriptManager instead of Page.ClientScript?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alert3", "alert3();", true);
```

Comment: Its Working Now there is an extra (-) in my aspx code inside script